# django chunk query set

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

i need to chunk my data for 8 items in every tr in my HTML file
how can i do that in Django

```
{% for pr in portfolio %}
<td>
<img src="{{ pr.logo.url }}" class="img-responsive" title="{{ pr.title }}">
</td>
{% if forloop.counter %}
</tr>
<tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```